# Displaying email without sending

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a code that send or display email automatically.

```
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With outmail
        .To = c.Value
        .BCC = "xxxxx@yyyyyy.com"
        .Subject = Range("B1")
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(s)
    On Error Resume Next
        .Attachments.Add (DFile1)
        .Attachments.Add (DFile2)
        .Attachments.Add (DFile3)
        .Attachments.Add (DFile4)
        .Attachments.Add (DFile5)
        '.Send     'to send directly
        .Display    'to display email
    End With
```

When i use `.Send` it works perfectly, but when I use `.Display` the macro runs correctly  but nothing gets displayed

Comment: Why do have `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: in case one of the attachment is not available

Comment: Remove that and run a test to see if it works. about the files not being available I'm sure there are other ways to check

Comment: good one ... it works ....  now i need to find another way to mention if file not available ... I will work on it Thanks

Comment: how about using  `If DFile1 <> "" Then` and do it for each file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your trying to do is check each attachment and then skip using `On Error Resume Next` so you can do this which I don't like it..

```
 On Error Resume Next
 .Attachments.Add (DFile1)
On Error Resume Next
 .Attachments.Add (DFile2)
On Error Resume Next
 .Attachments.Add (DFile3)
On Error Resume Next
 .Attachments.Add (DFile4)
On Error Resume Next
 .Attachments.Add (DFile5)
On Error GoTo 0
```

But what I will do is something like this

```
     '// Attachment Path
     AtmtsPath = "C:\Temp\"

    '// Add attachments to the message.
    Atmts = Dir(AtmtsPath & "*.*")

    Do While Len(Atmts) > 0
        .Attachments.Add AtmtsPath & Atmts 
        Atmts = Dir
    Loop
```